# SWT - Using EditingSupport in my TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

In my main dailog, I have a JFace TableViewer.  The last column of the table is a ComboBoxCellEditor.  They have the option of No, Yes, Both.  This all works as designed.

But here is my issue.

1. If the user selects Both for the value.
2. I need to run a method that will get current row data from the Array
3. Change the value from both to No
4. Make a copy of the data then change the value to Yes
5. Add both back in to the Array
6. Refresh the table

Table Example

From -

```
1002 | 001   | sss   |  part | both(user changed from default)
```

To -

```
1002 |  001  |  sss  |  part |  No

1002 |  001  |  sss  |  part | Yes
```

I am trying to figure out after both is selected how to run the method to do the rest.  I am assuming it has to be some sort of a listener.  Please have a look at my EditingSupport code and show me where I would start my method to do the rest.

```
public class OptionEditingSupport extends EditingSupport 
{
    private ComboBoxCellEditor cellEditor;

    public OptionEditingSupport(ColumnViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);
        cellEditor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(((TableViewer)viewer).getTable(), new String[]{"No", "Yes", "Both"}, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        //cellEditor.setValue(0);
    }
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return cellEditor;
    }
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        return 0;
    }
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) 
    {
        if((element instanceof AplotDatasetData) && (value instanceof Integer)) {
            Integer choice = (Integer)value;
            //String option = (choice == 0? "Yes":"No":"Both");
            String option = ((AplotDatasetData)element).getMarkupValue();;
            if(choice == 0) {
                option = "No";
            }    
            else if(choice == 1) {
                option = "Yes";
            }    
            else {
                option = "Both";
            }    
            ((AplotDatasetData)element).setMarkupValue(option);
            getViewer().update(element, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you want to duplicate one of your objects, add it to you model and refresh the viewer.

And all this should happen when the user selects `"both"` in the combobox. You already know, when this happens. You will end up in the `else` case of your `setValue` method. Then you can do what you have to do there:

```
protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) 
{
    if((element instanceof AplotDatasetData) && (value instanceof Integer)) {
        Integer choice = (Integer)value;

        String option = ((AplotDatasetData)element).getMarkupValue();

        if(choice == 0) {
            option = "No";
        }    
        else if(choice == 1) {
            option = "Yes";
        }    
        else {
            option = "Both";

            // create a copy of your element
            // add it to your model
            // update the viewer
        }

        getViewer().update(element, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: That is so obvious now that you have simply pointed to it.  Baz thank you very much for all your help.  I have learned quite a bit from your suggestions and explanations